# Printing tkinter askopenfile() input

Tags: python, tkinter

I want the code below to print the selected file, But im doing something wrong. the code gives me this error:

`TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper`

```
def open_file():
    global file
    global wb
    file = askopenfile(mode="a", filetypes=[("Excel Files", "*.xlsx *.xlsm *.sxc *.ods *.csv *.tsv")])
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=file.name)
    filename = os.path.basename(file)
    print(filename)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which line is the error occurring on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your error is on this line:

```
filename = os.path.basename(file)
```

It should be:

```
filename = os.path.basename(file.name)
```

The error states that you are not passing a path(string), bytes or `os.PathLike` object. Instead you are passing `_io.TextIOWrapper` object, as `file` is `_io.TextIOWrapper` object.

Comment: But, I also need to be able to read and write on that file.` askopenfilename` wouldnt let me do that, I believe